# How many parameters does GoogleNet have?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe

I wrote a simple script to calculate number of parameters a given architecture has. here it is :

```
#python caffe_param_calc.py deploy.prototxt
#or just call the script without any arguments, and it will search and show any deploy you have in the current directory

import sys
import os
import caffe
import numpy as np
from numpy import prod, sum
from pprint import pprint

def print_net_parameters (deploy_file):
    print "Net: " + deploy_file
    caffe.set_mode_cpu()
    net = caffe.Net(deploy_file, caffe.TEST)

    print "Layer-wise parameters: "
    pprint([(k, v[0].data.shape) for k, v in net.params.items()])
    num = sum( [prod(v[0].data.shape) for k, v in net.params.items()] )
    print ("Total number of parameters: {0:,} ".format(num))

print (len(sys.argv))
if len(sys.argv) > 1 :
    deploy_file = sys.argv[1]
else:
    for file in os.listdir('.'):
        if (file.endswith('.prototxt')):
           deploy_file = file

print_net_parameters(deploy_file)
```

I used this on GoogleNet and got `11,193,984` for the number of parameters used, while in their paper, if you add up all the parameters they list in table 1, the total number of parameters become 6.7M! and it seems that table is not accurate either!. My question now is, Am I doing this correctly? I used the same script on different architectures and got the correct result.
For example VGGNet ([Link](https://gist.github.com/ksimonyan/fd8800eeb36e276cd6f9#file-readme-md)) has a total number of parameters of 102,897,440.

```
Layer-wise parameters:
[('conv1', (96L, 3L, 7L, 7L)),
 ('conv2', (256L, 96L, 5L, 5L)),
 ('conv3', (512L, 256L, 3L, 3L)),
 ('conv4', (512L, 512L, 3L, 3L)),
 ('conv5', (512L, 512L, 3L, 3L)),
 ('fc6', (4096L, 18432L)),
 ('fc7', (4096L, 4096L)),
 ('fc8', (1000L, 4096L))]
Total number of parameters: 102,897,440
```

Comment: what about bias terms? be careful not to count parameters of `"BatchNorm"` layers.

Comment: @Shai: Batchnorm layers and scales are not taken into account. I tested both with batchnorm and without batch norm, and got the same number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

According to the paper (http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2015/papers/Szegedy_Going_Deeper_With_2015_CVPR_paper.pdf) and a short calculation it seems correct. The number of parameters in the GoogLeNet are produced by using an ensemble of networks. They combined 7 such networks for the output.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean the number of parameters is actually 11 million right?